# How to create multiple functions in C

Tags: c

I am new to C programming and I am trying to create functions.  The first function executes but the second one doesn't.

```
#include <stdio.h>
char get_char();
int main(void)
{
   char ch;
   printf("Enter a character > ");
   scanf("%c", &ch);
   return ch;
}

int get_int()
{
    int i;
    printf("Enter an integer between 0 and 127 > ");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Because the second function is not called?

Comment: The only function that's called automatically is `main()`. Everything else must be called explicitly from somewhere else.

Comment: Surely the chapter of your tutorial or textbook on functions explains this. Go read it again.

Comment: What @MikeCAT said. If you don't call a function, it doesn't run. That's pretty much the whole point of functions--separating out chunks of code to call them when you want and only when you want. Also, you really should format that code; it's extremely difficult to read in its current form.

Answer (score 1):

`main` is the *entry point* for your program. The C environment calls `main` when your program is executed. `get_int()` is not the name for an entry point, so the fact that you never call it directly or indirectly in `main` means it will never be executed.

You also didn't declare it before `main` meaning your compiler will warn about not finding it, but since `get_int` returns `int` it will link successfully regardless.

Fix:

```
int get_int();
int main ()
{
    //...
}
int get_int()
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that arrives here, you may solve your problem, by making sure your `main` function is at the bottom of the file.

Why? Because if `function a` calls `function b`, a should be before b.

Comment: nope, you can define the function later as long as you have a declaration earlier.

Answer (score -1):

Your second function isn't called and it should be as follows:

```
int main()
{
   int m = 10;
   get_int(m);

   return 0;
 }

 int get(int num)
 {
     int multiply = num * num;
     return multiply;
 }
```

Comment: Vote down! Never mind. I mistakenly pasted the code of the OP. I guess, the above will work fine.

Comment: you call get_int but write a function call get

Comment: In c functions are not searched like this. The compiler will look for a previously defined function or prototype when you call the function. But since neither of them is defined, it will give you an error. Now with your code: defining a get function and calling get_int will not work and will throw an error (this in all languages)

Comment: Ha, Don't be lazy, edit your answer. Such a short code doesn't take that much time.